# pass value of a textbox from view to controller using actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my form I have a textbox as below

```
@Html.TextBox("first_name")
```

I need to pass the value of this textbox to controller through a actionlink.

I tried the below

```
@Html.ActionLink("View", "view_Details", new { name = first_name})
```

but this is giving error

> "first_name" does not exist in the current context

Is this possible using a Actionlink?

My controller signature is

```
public ActionResult view_Details(string name)
     {
            return View();
     }
```

**Edited**

```
 @Html.ActionLink("View", "view_Details", new { name = getname()})

 <script type="text/javascript">
      function getname() {
           return $("#first_name").val();
       }
</script>
```

I tried above code. Its also giving error

> getname() does not exist in the current context

Comment: Your will need javascript/jquery to get the value of the textbox and then update the url

Comment: @stephenmuecke tried the same as edited part in the question

Comment: That's because razor code is parsed on the server before its send to the view. `getname()` is a client side method which does not exist at that point. I'll post a answer shortly showing how you can do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need javascript/jquery to get the value of the textbox and then update the url you want to redirect to

Html

```
@Html.ActionLink("View", "view_Details", new { id = "myLink" }) // add id attribute
```

Script

```
$('#myLink').click(function() {
  var firstname = $('#first_name').val(); // get the textbox value
  var url = $(this).attr('href') + '?name=' + firstname; // build new url
  location.href = url; // redirect
  return false; // cancel default redirect
});
```

Side note: further to you edit, the reason you receive that error is that razor code (the `@Html.ActionLink()` is parsed on the server before its sent to the view but `getname()` is a client side method which does not exist at that point - i.e it *does not exist in the current context*

Comment: how will i create the url if i need to pass some model value also?

Comment: Do you mean say the `ID` property of the model? - in which case you could add `var id = '@Model.ID';` and then `var url = $(this).attr('href') + '?name=' + firstname + '&id=' + id;`