# MVC5 actionLink send textbox value to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have textbox

```
@Html.TextBox("report_id", null, new { @class = "form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12", @Value = @ViewBag.Reports_ID, @readonly = true })
```

i want use actionlink to send textbox value to controller. but i can't get textbox value.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Preview", "Update", "Home", new { @report_id = Request.QueryString["report_id "] }, new { @class = "btn btn-info", target = "_blank" })
```

Pls help, Thanks

Comment: You need javascript to update the `href` attribute of the link based on the edited value in the textbox (or just enclose the textbox in a form with `FormMethod.Get`. And there is no point adding `new { @report_id = Request.QueryString["report_id "] }` - that's just adding the original value of `report_id`

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581409/pass-value-of-a-textbox-from-view-to-controller-using-actionlink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First give an ID attribute to the action link like below:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Preview", "Update", "Home", new { @report_id = Request.QueryString["report_id "] }, new { @class = "btn btn-info", target = "_blank", id="alink" })
```

Then write a jQuery click event function for the ActionLink:

```
$("#alink").click(function () {
    $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href") + "?id=" + $("#report_id").val());
});
```

See if it will work for you.

Comment: Hi Faisal, Thanks

Comment: Hi @Faisal, follow you code, i can get textbox id. But I press "preview" button 2 times more, address link will general so much "report_id". see "/Reports/Home/Update?report_id=161024001?report_id=161024001?report_id=161024001".

Comment: In that case need to check if the id parameter already exists before adding it again. Something like: var url =$(this).attr("href"); if(url.indexOf('?report_id=') == -1) {$(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href") + "?report_id=" + $("#report_id").val());}

Comment: Great! Glad to know that it helped you. Please mark the answer.