# Pass texbox value to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm planing to design star rating control in MVC. I've design input text to store rating value. I want to pass the input text with action link.

How to do that?

```
<input type="text" name="votenumber" class="ratingEvent rating5" value="5" />
<div><b id="result">5</b> start(s)</div>

@Html.ActionLink("Vote", "Vote", "Home")
```

Pass the input value to the action link or better idea pass to controller?

The `b id= result` will immediately change value when user selected others value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31581939

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think so , the better way is use jquery ajax and send it via this , such as this code

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Vote',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { search: $('#your text box').val()},
        success: function (result) {
            $('#your result div').html(result);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: what is url and type ? any example ?

Comment: For example , you can set type to Get or Post ,depend on your action.

Comment: See answer , I add url and type for you.

Comment: thx man, i get the idea.